# Building marisa-trie shared library with msys/mingw64

Tags: c++, automake, msys, mingw-w64

Trying to build [marisa-trie](https://code.google.com/p/marisa-trie/downloads/detail?name=marisa-0.2.4.tar.gz) library in msys using MinGW64.

```
./configure --prefix=/e/SDK/env-gcc-4.8-64bit --enable-sse2 --enable-sse3 --enable-ssse3 --enable-sse4 --enable-sse4.1 --enable-sse4.2
make
```

That produces only a static library, no shared. Adding "--enable-shared=yes" does not change anything. Adding "--enable-static=no" produces a Makefile that does nothing.

What is wrong with that distribution and how to fix it?

**edit:** [This seems to fix it](https://github.com/fd00/yacp/blob/master/marisa/marisa-0.2.4-1bl2.src.patch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found by sheer luck.

[This seems to fix it.](https://github.com/fd00/yacp/blob/master/marisa/marisa-0.2.4-1bl2.src.patch)